# How to add system date in the title

Tags: sas

How can I add the system date in the body and by doing this, will it generate a new file without replacing the old one? Thanks in advance.

```
ods listing CLOSE;
ods HTML path="drive:\folder" body='title-(systemdate).html' style = 
styles.test; 
OPTION LS=195 PS=500 ;
TITLE; FOOTNOTE;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the automatic macro variable `&sysdate9`.

```
body="title-(&sysdate9.).html"
```

Make sure you use double quotes.

If you don't want that format, then you can use that variable and a `putn` call to reformat it.

```
%let new_dt = %sysfunc(putn("&sysdate9."d,mmddyyd10.));
...
body="title-(&new_dt.).html"
```

Note: `&sysdate9` is set when the session starts.  It is not the date as of being called, it is as of SAS starting up.

If you want the current date, use `date()` function.

```
%let new_dt = %sysfunc(putn(%sysfunc(date()),mmddyyd10.));
...
body="title-(&new_dt.).html"
```

Comment: `%sysfunc` has an optional parameter where you can specify a format, so your 2nd example can be shortened to `%let new_dt = %sysfunc(date(),mmddyyd10.);`